# ASP.NET Web Api IOwinContext changes are not saved

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to create OWIN middleware where I update some properties of `IOwinContext`. Exactly `Principle` property, change it or add more identities. After updating I want to access it in AuthorizationFilter, but all my changes are missing. So I have two questions:
1) Where did my changes gone?
2) Is it even possible to update or change principal (or identity)?

Comment: are you sure that your middleware is registered to run before web api? Please show the code registering middlewares.

Comment: @KhanhTO yeah, i'm pretty sure. It is running `Invoke` method when i'm debugging,

Comment: is there any other middleware that may override your changes?

Comment: @KhanhTO No, i have two middlewares and they are both running on different pipeline stages: ResolveCache and PostAuntheticate. I'm interested in PostAuthenticate middleware